# using a map with a comparator as a std::map parameter

Tags: c++, casting, comparator, stdmap

Say I define a map with a custom comparator such as

```
struct Obj
{
    int id;
    std::string data;
    std::vector<std::string> moreData;
};
struct Comparator
{
    using is_transparent = std::true_type;
    bool operator()(Obj const& obj1, Obj const& obj2) { return obj1.id < obj2.id; };
}
std::map<Obj,int,Comparator> compMap;
```

is there a good way to ensure that downstream users don't have to implement the comparator to use the map as a map?

for instance my compiler throws an error if I try to pass it to a function with a similar type.

```
template<class T>
inline void add(std::map<T, int>& theMap, T const & keyObj)
{
    auto IT = theMap.find(keyObj);
    if (IT != theMap.end())
        IT->second++;
    else
        theMap[keyObj] = 1;
}
add(compMap,newObj); //type error here
```

EDIT:
I kinda over santitized this to make a generic case. and then overlooked the obvious

```
template<class T, class Comp, class Alloc>
inline void add(std::map<T, int, Comp, Alloc>& theMap, T const & keyObj)
```

still having issues with one use not being able to deduce T, but went from 80 erros to 1 so... progress
thanks everyone.

Comment: What makes you think that casting is a good solution to this (even if it worked)?  Why not just use the proper types?

Comment: Your comparator appears to be a very opaque comparator, rather than a  transparent one. And what did you mean by "copy around the comparator", exactly?

Comment: Implicit conversion between `std::map<Obj,int>` and `std::map<Obj,int,Comparator>`? Not gonna happen. You don't even know, if both would require the same number of entries. E.g. consider 2 `std::map<int, int, Comp>` one, with the default comparator and one comparing the keys `k1` and `k2` as `(k1 % 2) < (k2 % 2)`. Why bother though? If the user is a reasonably competent programmer, they could have used `template<class Comp, class Allocator> void(std::map<Obj, int, Comp, Allocator>* theMap, Obj const& keyObj) ...` or even `template<class Map> void add(Map& theMap, Obj const& keyObj)`...

Comment: @fabian Thats a good point. also adding the comp and allocator to templates fixed things that weren't even fixed by using the actual type directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can typedef the specialised type and use that type inplace of

```
std::map<...

typedef std::map<Obj,int,Comparator> compMap_t;

inline void add(compMap_t& theMap, Obj const & keyObj)
    ...
```

Comment: I did try this but it seems like the compiler didn't do a great job of distinguishing between 
`void add(compMap_t & theMap, Obj const & keyObj)` and the existing `void add(std::map<Obj,int> & theMap, Obj const & keyObj)` and has a tendency to fall into the wrong one. using a template to pass the comparator and allocator in either case seemed to work better.

Comment: Why would you want both versions of add? Just use the one with the typedef type and when you want to create an instance of the map, just use the typedef.

Comment: That's basically what i did in the end. I thought I would need separate funcs but it ended up combining well into one function.
I didn't say it in the initial question but I was actually doing 
`template<class T> add(<std::map<T,int>,T)` initially because a lot of classes used it and I overgenerzied my question and overlooked the obvious answer to use more templates

Answer (score 1):

Downstream users either use the type declared by you

```
using my_important_map = std::map<Obj,int,Comparator>;
```

or better use functions which take a generic map type,

```
auto some_function(auto const& map_)
{
     //do something with the map and don't care about the ordering
     return map_.find(Obj(1));
}
```